# How to filter array with adding missing element from other array and replace repeated item

Tags: objective-c

I have array with objects `[Object.id = 1, Object.id = 2, Object.id = 3, Object.id = 4, Object.id = 5]` and I have another array `[Object.id = 0, Object.id = 2]`

So I want to see result:

```
[Object.id = 0, Object.id = 1, Object.id = 2, Object.id = 3, Object.id = 4, Object.id = 5]
```

and in teh same time `Object.id = 2` should be inserted from the second array and `Object.id = 2` from first array should be skipped. So kind of much, combine and replace operation.

```
+ (NSArray *)savedRecords:(NSArray *)records
{
  NSArray *pendingNotPaidrecords = [self pendingNotPaidRecords];

  if (pendingNotPaidRecords.count == 0) {
    return records;
  }

  NSMutableArray *remoterecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:records];
  NSMutableArray *filteredrecords = [NSMutableArray new];

  for (Record *localrecord in pendingNotPaidrecords) {
    record *temprecord = nil;

    for (Record *record in records) {
      if ([record.recordId integerValue] == [localrecord.recordId integerValue]) {
        [remoterecords removeObjectIdenticalTo:record];
        temprecord = localrecord;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (temprecord) {
      [filteredrecords addObject:temprecord];
    } else {
      [filteredrecords addObject:localrecord];
    }
  }

  NSArray *combinedArray = [filteredrecords arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:remoterecords];

  return combinedArray;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with relevant code showing what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy, just updated a code. So the goal is to merge two arrays. So if we have records which is the same we should pick records from the second array and put them to temp array. If the record does not exist in first array we just need to find it and put to temp array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but hey it works.

```
var array1 = [Object(id: 1), Object(id: 2)]
var array2 = [Object(id: 0), Object(id: 2)]

// Keep original.
array1.append(contentsOf: array2.filter{ a in !array1.contains{ b in b.id == a.id } })

// Replace original with duplicate.
array1 = array1.filter{ a in !array2.contains{ b in b.id == a.id } } + array2
```

Comment: sorry, I corrected my self, I use objective - c here.

Comment: in Swift very elegant, I guess we should keep this answer here as well. nice example

Comment: Ah, ok! And well, it's alright for a one-liner, but maybe a bit more complex than it would need to be.

Comment: And apparently I misread the question, this doesn't replace the object from the first array, just skips the second...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
// remove the ids of array2 from array1
NSArray *array = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id in %@)", [array2 valueForKey:@"id"]]];
// add elements of array2
array = [array arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array2];
// sort by id
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES]]];
```

Or the same procedure using a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
// remove the ids of array2 from array1
[mutableArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (id in %@)", [array2 valueForKey:@"id"]]];
// add elements of array2
[mutableArray addObjectsFromArray:array2];
// sort by id
[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES]]];
```